# Blocking access to Exchange from mobile devices....sorta

Tags: exchange-2013, mdm

We use an MDM solution to control access to email; if you're not using the MDM, you don't get email, simple as that.  However, there's one exception to the rule...the CEO.  Without getting into that discussion/argument, is there anyway I can tell Exchange/IIS to not give email to certain users unless they come in on the MDM IP address?

I used to lock down email access to the IP address of the MDM servers, but that won't work in this situation as a mobile device can take on many IP addresses.

Thanks

Comment: `"We use an MDM solution to control access to email; if you're not using the MDM, you don't get email, simple as that. However, there's one exception to the rule...the CEO"` - so are you asking how to allow your CEO access to the Exchange server without going through the MDM and without removing the current restriction for everyone else?  And are we talking Activesync or OWA or what from these mobile devices?  It almost seems a little odd to use an MDM to restrict access to Exchange when Exchange itself has an MDM of sorts within itself.

Comment: Elaborate... what's an "*MDM*"?

Comment: I had to remove the restriction; we tell everyone they have to go through the MDM to get email, but it's not accurate.  I would like to make everyone have to go through the MDM to get email, but allow the CEO to access directly.  Normally you block all by restricting access by IP address in IIS.  As far as I know it's OWA (or something like it)   There is an MDM in Exchange, but it's hardly full featured.